# Async Threads beginoutputreadline c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, process

I Have Written a Console Program that Gives Data from Another Console Program That Write Lines of Data frequently after 3 or more seconds , So I Try Read output Data from Console by BeginOutputReadLine That is an async Method and OutputDataRecieved event but after reads some Lines its threads exit and it goes to an interval for 3 or more minutes, what should I do to prevent from this interval ?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FirstTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("start.bat")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = info };
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {               
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
            });
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}
```

The Debug Outputs are below :

The thread 0x2030 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 0x3b2c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code for reading output stream from the process object:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    FileName = "start.bat",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
var process = new Process {
    StartInfo = info
};
```

then start the process and read from it:

```
process.Start();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    var outputLine = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // do something with the outputLine
}
```

Comment: Ohh I spent all day trying to solve this one. I'm commenting so Google finds this better because it really helped me with an issue where ActionBlock wasn't completing all the tasks, the results were getting lost, randomly. I honestly thought ActionBlock had a bug. Turns out The BeginOutputReadLine was messing everything up.